# delete vertices in r , as a network object

Tags: r

I have some data like below, this data can be found in library network, 
when I try list.vertex.attributes(v), it gives me the "Grade"        "na"           "Race"         "Sex"          "vertex.names", so I want to delete some node with Race="natAm", 
I have tried this code but my delete function does not work.
can you help me?

```
data(faux.magnolia.high)
v<- faux.magnolia.high
v
gr <- v %v% "Race"
table(gr)

del <- v %v% "Race"
n2 <- v %s% which(del== "NatAm")
n2
y<-delete.vertices(n,c(114,890)) 
y
```

also this line gr <- v %v% "Race", give this output:

```
Asian Black  Hisp NatAm Other White 
   48   261    68    24     7  1053
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete vertices where `Race=="NatAm"`, you can indicate this in the `vid` argument of `delete.vertices()`. But **beware**--`delete.vertices()` modifies the network **in place**!

```r
library(statnet)

data(faux.magnolia.high)
v<- faux.magnolia.high
v
#>  Network attributes:
#>   vertices = 1461 
#>   directed = FALSE 
#>   hyper = FALSE 
#>   loops = FALSE 
#>   multiple = FALSE 
#>   bipartite = FALSE 
#>   total edges= 974 
#>     missing edges= 0 
#>     non-missing edges= 974 
#> 
#>  Vertex attribute names: 
#>     Grade Race Sex vertex.names 
#> 
#>  Edge attribute names not shown
gr <- v %v% "Race"
table(gr)
#> gr
#> Asian Black  Hisp NatAm Other White 
#>    48   261    68    24     7  1053

# Deletes in place!
delete.vertices(v, vid = which(v %v% "Race"=="NatAm"))
gr <- v %v% "Race"
table(gr)
#> gr
#> Asian Black  Hisp Other White 
#>    48   261    68     7  1053
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>